# What's the difference between "btn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler (ButtonClick)" and "btn.Click += ButtonClick"?

Tags: c#, wpf

In C#, when registering a event handler, you have two options (`btn` is of type `System.Windows.Controls.Button`):

`btn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler (ButtonClick)`
and

`btn.Click += ButtonClick`.

What's the semantic difference between them and their implications?

Comment: (The duplicate is for a different type, but it's the same basic question.)

Comment: Indeed, I did not find these previous questions with my keywords. Thanks for pointing it out - I flagged it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first version will compile without errors on all versions of .Net.

The second version will only compile on .Net 2 or later.

And that's the *only* difference. The second version is just some syntactic sugar introduced with .Net 2.

It's known as Method Group Conversion. See here for details:

http://mike-ward.net/blog/post/00020/anonymous-methods-method-group-conversions-and-eventhandler

Answer (score 3):

As I understood it, nothing, the compiler will infer the delegate type and wrap it for you automatically, it's just a shorthand way of doing it (because who really wants to type it all out).

Comment: basically, from what I just red, the syntax with new keyword works for framework 1.1, without it, it will give compiler error, that's why it is the default one in intellisense.

Comment: Yes I recall, because of that I tend to always do the long way.

Answer (score 1):

There is no differences. To understand these C# feature, you should read C# **delegate** and **event** keyword.